# Vue app not able to connect to Docker Redis

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, npm, redis

I have a vue app which uses redis for storing user session. But when I am trying to run the app after installing the docker redis, it is not able to connect to the docker redis.
I am working on windows 10.

The error while starting the app is

```
(node:11656) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

 ERROR  Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379                                                                                                               22:40:02

  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)


 ERROR  Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379                                                                                                               22:40:04

  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
```

But when I issue the below command in the windows terminal I am getting the result fine

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS      NAMES
7883e98ea39a   redis     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 hours ago   Up 6 hours   6379/tcp   local-redis
```

why the app is not able to connect to local docker redis

I created the redis docker image via this command :

```
docker run --name local-redis -d redis
```

Comment: It is not vuejs related. I feel like you forgot the port forward ( -p 6379:6379)

Comment: yes it is working now after I added the port forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to open the port by recreating the redis image by the following command where I added the port forwarding part

```
 docker run -d --name local-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
```